# autossh working fine from terminal, bot causing permission denied from systemctl

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys, systemctl

I'm trying to integrate autossh on a raspberry pi.

if I launch the command by itself

```
autossh -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -N -R 22002:localhost:22 user@myserver
```

everything works fine, but launching the same command from systemctl

```
[Unit]
Description=AutoSSH tunnel service Remote port 22002 to local 22
After=network.target
[Service]
Environment="AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -N -R 22002:localhost:22 user@myserver.com
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

returns

```
Jun 25 13:43:22 pi autossh[995]: Permission denied, please try again.
Jun 25 13:43:22 pi autossh[995]: Permission denied, please try again.
Jun 25 13:43:22 pi autossh[995]: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Jun 25 13:43:22 pi autossh[995]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
```

I am able to ssh my server without password from my pi.

The log in /var/log/auth.log gives me this

```
Jun 26 13:00:51 localhost sshd[9252]: Connection closed by 178.135.1.253 port 41786 [preauth]
Jun 26 13:00:51 localhost sshd[9254]: Connection closed by 178.135.1.253 port 41788 [preauth]
Jun 26 13:00:51 localhost sshd[9256]: Connection closed by 178.135.1.253 port 41790 [preauth]
Jun 26 13:00:51 localhost sshd[9258]: Connection closed by 178.135.1.253 port 41792 [preauth]
Jun 26 13:00:52 localhost sshd[9260]: Connection closed by 178.135.1.253 port 41794 [preauth]
Jun 26 13:00:52 localhost sshd[9262]: Connection closed by 178.135.1.253 port 41796 [preauth]
Jun 26 13:00:54 localhost sshd[9264]: Connection closed by 178.135.1.253 port 41798 [preauth]
Jun 26 13:01:03 localhost sshd[9267]: Connection closed by 178.135.1.253 port 41802 [preauth]
Jun 26 13:01:05 localhost sshd[9269]: Connection closed by 178.135.1.253 port 41804 [preauth]
```

anything i should check up or do ?

Thanks,

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: I updated my question with the server log

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it, I simply had to add the user, because the key is for the user and systemd runs as root

```
[Service]
User=myuser
```